# Eclipse failure to handle two main.xml

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I am trying to design my application so that it has one main.xml layout for portrait and one main.xml layout for landscape. From the reading I've done, it seems that the way to go about this is like so: res/layout-land/main.xml for your landscape file and res/layout/main.xml for your portrait.

When working on this code in Eclipse 3.5.2, if I try to open one of the main.xml while the other is open, it seems to open it but in the exact same window as the other so I can't see them both at once, not even their tabs. That was annoying enough but it appears as though it thinks they are the same file because when it did let me make changes to one of them, it would seem that the changes were often as not to the wrong one (landscape when I was editing portrait and vice versa). All of that I could deal with, but frequently it is asking me if I was to edit a derived file when I try to edit one of the main.xml files, which makes me feel certain it thinks they are the same.

Am I missing something here? My impression was that you were supposed to have the layout files as the same filename and android would choose the proper one based on the folder path. Why can't Eclipse tell they are from different folders?
Also I have seen examples of code where their portrait main.xml was in res/layout-port/main.xml but that causes the same errors. Also I running this on the latest stable Ubuntu, 11.04 not that that should matter.

Comment: eclipse will use the same tab, but it shouldn't be editing the same file.  Works for me in 3.6.2.  Otherwise your setup/interpretation sound correct.

Comment: In my frustration it appears I was not as thorough as I should have been; after closing and reopening Eclipse, if I just close one of the files before I open the other one, it asks me about editing a derived file and if I say yes then everything seems to work ok. I still don't understand the problem but at least I have a workaround.

Comment: @djg if it uses the same tab (which doesnt seem like a good idea) then how do you know which file you are editing? you dont get the warnings about editing a derived file?

Comment: No derived file warnings.  Hover over the tab shows the full path.

Comment: @djg oh ok cool, that answer below is what i needed but the hover to file path thing will be just as useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the android layout editor (and not eclipse proper)... Try opening the files via right click -> Open with / XML editor.  That will yield the separate tabs that you are looking for.

Comment: awesome! i suppose i probably could have figured that out eventually but im rather new to eclipse, so learning how to use it has been at least as big of a hurdle as remembering how to code java

Comment: hrm very odd, now it doesnt do the graphical xml thing it used to do where it what show you what the code was going to look like, it now has a design tab and a source tab, the design tab looks sort of like a list of the views, sort of similar to the hierarchy viewer. but still preferably to not being able to have two main.xml open

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I found no other solution than to re-install Eclipse (latest Helios from their homepage) and delete .metadata from /workspace (also removed all of my other projects, have them on backup).

Re-downloaded the ADT plugin via Eclipse, works for me now. Everything including graphical editor.

Comment: huh thats interesting. ill have to try that later once ive finished this project.